# How to custom a container that changes its color when waiting for the data to be loaded in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to custom a container to change its color when loading the data, I want the container to start with Dark Grey Color and after 1 second to be Light Grey Color and to be repeated until the data is loaded as the image below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check following package called :shimmer

https://pub.dev/packages/shimmer